# Command to leave a RotMG guild

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

**To join a guild I can type `/join` GuildName. Is there a command to leave the guild?**

I confuse join-guild and trade menu so often that I would like to know a quick way to undo it. (Going to the nexus is not quick enough). Also there is commands like `/ignore` and `/unignor`e I think there should be a command oposite to `/join` shouldn't it?
I tried `/unjoin` and `/renounce` they do not work.

Comment: `/gquit` , `/gleave`, `/quit` any of these maybe. And see [this link](http://www.kongregate.com/forums/103-realm-of-the-mad-god/topics/249468-how-do-you-leave-a-guild)

Comment: @Damek, all of these are "unrecognized commands"

Comment: oke, it were just guesses though. Did the link helped anything? Looks a pretty easy google question tbh.

Comment: @Damek, i saw this link, but it proposes only the slow solution via nexus, isn't it? Google doesn't help.

Comment: Yes, I googled it, that's the only solution I saw. Don't play the game myself so can't help you any further.

Answer (score 3):

There is no command to leave a guild.

These are the available chat commands as of Release 21.2.1:

`/tell <player name> <text>` or `/t <player name> <text>`

`/who`

`/help`

`/lock <player name>`

`/unlock <player name>`

`/ignore <player name>`

`/unignore <player name>`

`/tutorial`

`/pause`

`/trade <player name>`

`/teleport <player name>`

`/server`

`/yell <text>`

`/invite <player name>`

`/join <guild name>`

`/nexustutorial`